# Remove extra space of the buttons below Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml

[image]

There's this extra space below the buttons, and I dont know why is it there. I tried everything and looked for anyone who have had this kind of problem and sadly i found nothing. It's either I want to remove the extra space and/or lower it down perfectly aligned.

Here's my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/button_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#262626"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/receipts_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/preview_save_icon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/capture_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/preview_upload_icon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/settings_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/preview_discard_icon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you are using a button instead of ImageView? You are using `android:drawableTop` which will position your image in the top part and leave some space in the bottom for text! 
As you don't want text, I'ts easier to replace it with `ImageView` and set the image as source. So it will be centered on the view:

```
  <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/button_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#262626"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/receipts_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"                
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/capture_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"                
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/settings_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just in case you haven't tried it RKN answer below would also have centered the icons but it also would have stretched them to fill in the  whole space. You can play around with background and src depending on which behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this, 
actually when you set android:gravity="center" its belongs to layout itself and when you say layout_gravity then this will apply to layout's child.

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not a good practice to have many nested Layouts. In your case you could remove either the LinearLayout or the RelativeLayout. Beyond that, although it would be helpfull to post the whole xml,
I would suggest removing the `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in the LinearLayout, and maybe adding   something like: `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`

Answer (score 0):

- Remove `android:drawableTop` attribute and give `Button` image  in
  `android:background` attribute. `android:drawableTop` will position your image in the top part.
- Set the `layout_gravity` attribute to `center_vertical` for the
  buttons

  ```
  <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/button_layout"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#262626"
          android:gravity="center">
          <Button 
              android:id="@+id/receipts_button"
              android:background="@drawable/preview_save_icon"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_weight="1"/>
          <Button android:id="@+id/capture_button"
              android:background="@drawable/preview_upload_icon"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_weight="1"/>
          <Button android:id="@+id/settings_button"
              android:background="@drawable/preview_discard_icon"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_weight="1"/>
      </LinearLayout>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this is correctly told by **gameower**.
In addition to that, if you want to continue using `Buttons` then you just need to replace `android:drawableTop` by `android:drawableLeft` and you should get what you want.

Hope that hepls.